# How to create a php script which make function run in background?

Tags: php

I want to create a function which runs in the background. An example would be deleting a session from database (`id`,`session_token`, `session_identifier`, `expired_time`). Once it's expire the current page will **automatically** redirect user back to the login page (`login.php`).

**UPDATE**

The expired time is stored in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using `jquery` Ajax and `setInterval` function

```
 function check_login() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: "http://stackoverflow.com", /*Where you will check user is logged in or not means session is expired or not*/
                beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    /*ajax call will return "Still login" (or any other response) if login*/
                    if (response == 'Still login') {
                        return true;
                    } else if (response == 'not login') {
                        window.location.replace("http://domain.com/login.php");
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        setInterval(check_login, 100);
```

Comment: Run the whole code on console you will find how this function will work

Comment: In `url`, do i `return` or `echo`  'Still login' as a response?

Comment: just echo 1 for still log in and 0 for not log in.

Comment: But this is not a good approach response must be in json encoded format. Just try it first and then if success, after that you can go for json response.

Answer (score 0):

Php Cronjob will be better approach for this. Cronjob is a way to run scheduled task in background.

Please have a look at the following link:

**http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml**